# Seeking Help in Creating a Function with Bumps for Teaching Multivariable Extrema

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am currently preparing a class on finding the extremum of multivariable functions and would appreciate some assistance. I intend to use Geogebra to aid in my teaching, and I am looking for a function that exhibits multiple "bumps" similar to the image I have provided. The ideal function would allow me to manipulate the view and animate it during the class.

[image]

If anyone could help me generate such a function or provide guidance on how to create one, I would be extremely grateful. Your expertise and support would greatly enhance my teaching materials.

Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance.

Comment: $A\sin x + B\sin y$? Maybe make $A, B$ themselves functions of $(x,y)$ to get bumps of differing heights. Also $f(x,y)\sin(ax + by)$.